# How do I merge these 2 queries looking at 2 tables into 1 query?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables I need to query with similar contents but differing field names.

I'm wanting to merge the following 2 queries into 1 so that I have 1 set of results.

The 2 queries are:

```
  SELECT 
    bookings.booking_name,
    bookings.booking_email,
    bookings.booking_mobile
  FROM 
    bookings   
  WHERE 
  ( bookings.booking_email LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  OR 
    bookings.booking_name LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  OR 
    bookings.booking_mobile LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  )


SELECT 
    purchases.customer_name,
    purchases.customer_email,
    purchases.customer_phone
FROM 
 handbags
WHERE   
  ( purchases.customer_email LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  OR 
    purchases.customer_name LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  OR 
    purchases.customer_phone LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  )
```

How is this sort of thing accomplished so that in my result customer_email and booking_email can be accessed simply by 'email'.

Comment: Google for "SQL Injection" and realize that this code has a huge security hole.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that. This sql is happening behind a secure login for an office environment so its not a big risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two queries with the [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) operator, and give the columns matching names.

```
(SELECT 
  bookings.booking_name AS name,
  bookings.booking_email AS email,
  bookings.booking_mobile AS phone
FROM 
  bookings   
WHERE 
( bookings.booking_email LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  OR 
  bookings.booking_name LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  OR 
  bookings.booking_mobile LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
))
UNION
(
SELECT 
  purchases.customer_name AS name,
  purchases.customer_email AS email,
  purchases.customer_phone AS phone
FROM 
 handbags
WHERE   
( purchases.customer_email LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  OR 
  purchases.customer_name LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
  OR 
  purchases.customer_phone LIKE "%' . $_POST['val'] . '%"
));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. With this sort of query though when I print the results I have 2 variables in an array ie customer_name and booking_name - how do I merge that?

Comment: @KeenLearner Sorry for initially rejecting the edit, I made a mistake but it was too late to correct it.

Comment: Sorry i cant get you. Merging customer_name and booking_name? you mean to say relation?? Join??

Answer (score 2):

`union [all]` them together:

```
select ...
union
select ...
```

adding 'all' will allow for duplicates.

Comment: thanks Anton. I'm a bit of a newb and now that I've seen the larger example I can make sense of yours.